# PIG - STORING TEMPORARY VALUES

Tags: apache-pig

Data schema :   `sdesc:chararray,samt:init,syear:chararrary,stype:chararrary`

Data:

```
Wrench 259000 2000 store
Wrench 135000 2000 online
Wrench 175000 2001 online 
Wrench 180000 2001 store
```

Script

```
ysales =LOAD ‘salesdata.txt’ using PigStorage()as (sdesc:chararray,samt:init,syear:chararrary,stype:chararrary);
basedata = FILTER ysales by (sdesc==’Wrench’) and (syear = ‘2000’ ) and (stype = ‘store);
```

my result set is : DUMP basedata;

```
(Wrench,259000,2000,store)
```

So the question is  how do I break up  basedata  to have (for example)  `A = ‘Wrench’  B = 259000, C=2000, D = ‘store’`

Comment: What is A,B,C,D? Will it store only one value? What if filtered records are more than 1 record and in  that case what will have to be stored in A,B,C,D?

Comment: To answer your question, from the result set, is there a way to  store "wrench" in  'a',  25900 in b  '2000' in c   and 'store' in "d'      In other words, break up the result set  and store them in temporary variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use argument numbers to extract values according to columns

```
a = foreach basedata generate $0;
b = foreach basedata generate $1;
c = foreach basedata generate $2;
d = foreach basedata generate $3;
```

Answer (score 0):

`data = load '/home/satish/wrench' using PigStorage(' ') as (name,total,year,type) ;`

//if you want to use you can use filter

```
reqdata = foreach data generate CONCAT('A','=',name) as A, CONCAT('B','=',total) as B, CONCAT('C','=',year) as C,CONCAT('D','=',type) as D;
```

`dump reqdata`;

`(A=Wrench,B=259000,C=2000,D=store)
(A=Wrench,B=135000,C=2000,D=online)
(A=Wrench,B=175000,C=2001,D=online)
(A=Wrench,B=180000,C=2001,D=store)`

`fdata = foreach reqdata generate A,B;`

`dump fdata`

`(A=Wrench,B=259000)
(A=Wrench,B=135000)
(A=Wrench,B=175000)
(A=Wrench,B=180000)`

\if you want to remove tuples use FLATTEN

Comment: I was looking at Flatten. I will post the results

Comment: sales2000 = LOAD 'retailsales.txt'  USING PigStorage()
AS (sdesc:chararray,samt:int,syear:chararray,stype:chararray);
basedesc = FILTER sales2000 by syear=='2000' AND sdesc=='Retail and food services sales  total';
basedes2000 = FOREACH basedesc generate $0;
basesamt = FOREACH basedesc generate $1; 
basesyear = FOREACH basedesc generate $2;
basestype = FOREACH basedesc generate $3;
DUMP basedes2000;
DUMP basesyamt;
DUMP basesyear;
DUMP basestype;